# I want a script to decrypt the encrypted stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure with encryption.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Example 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'SQL statements' 
END
```

When I used query `sp_helptext` 'Example' I am being told

> The object comments have been encrypted

I want a script to decrypt the encrypted stored procedure so that when I used `sp_helptext` I would be able to see the logic.

Comment: I checked google and found this guide: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/